# Run rake task before rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I need to run a certain rake task (copying a shared config file) right before my rails server starts. The only solution I found, was to create a new rake task like `rake server` which is doing `rake copy_file; rails s`. As other developers might be confused with a new rake task to start developing our application I want to stick with `rails s`. Maybe somebody has an idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make yourself an initializer file and do your rake task there before the server starts

```
# config/initializers/some_initializer.rb
require 'rake'
rake copy_file
```

Or if you don't want to use an initializer you can make a `rails s` alias for your repo

```
# config/custom_aliases.sh
echo "you've refreshed your aliases!"

myRailsFunction() {
  if [ $1 == 's' ]
  then
    rake copy_file
    echo 'ran rake copy_file'
    rails $1
  else
    rails $1
  fi
}
alias rails=myRailsFunction
```

and in order to use this for the first time you need to run this

```
source ~/your_repo/config/custom_aliases.sh
```

and now this will both run your server and call the rake task

```
rails s
```

Comment: I also thought about using an initializer but I feel like this is the wrong place for copying files around. What I forgot to mention was that this is only needed on our development environment and if I put it in an initializer I would need to check if it's the development environement and add a new file, which is increasing the complexity.

Comment: I just want to have "build" related things separated from initialisations.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a non-initializer way of doing this

Comment: Just fixed something in that alias just now so that you can still use ```rails c``` as well as ```rails s``` and others